# hide application from android application chooser

Tags: android, hide, autosuggest

Hi
I created an application (BookReader) that parses and displays a certain book (given as the default book).
But if I simply copy any other book on my device and attempt to open it, android displays a list of suggested installed applications that can open my book. Among these suggested applications is my app (BookReader) too and if selected it opens that book.
How can set my app so it won't appear in the suggested android apps list? Because I don't want my app to be used for opening other books. Just the default one.

Thanks

NOTE! I want it to appear in the application list. I just don't want to appear as a app suggestion for opening other books or files.

Answer (score 2):

thanks guys! 
I solved it by removing the mimeTypes in the manifest file which were inside the intent-filter that was a match for the action of opening those file formats.
Hope this helps others too

Answer (score 0):

Your application is probably registering for an intent that matches the intent used by any book. You probably want to modify your IntentFilter to narrow the scope to only match your specific book somehow. What intent does your book generate?

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion. It really helped. I posted an answer with the solution but a moderator deleted it [i don't know why]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the AndroidManifest.xml to remove the IntentFilter that listens for books. If you paste the contents of this file, I can provide more exact details.

Did you take an open source eBook reader and try to package individual books as their own applications?

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion. It really helped. I posted an answer with the solution but a moderator deleted it [i don't know why]